# Entity Framework 4: inheritance and Associations

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance

I do derive my entities from a base-class that provides tracking.

[image]

Since `User` derives from `TrackableBase` and `TrackableBase` is associated with `User`, I get an error:

> "Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations.
>   Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model
>   requirements or store generated values."

Is this model just not possible, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When do you get that error? What operations are you doing when you get that error?

Comment: I get the error once I do "SaveChanges".

Comment: Yes but what you did before `SaveChanges` - that error is not about your model but about operations you instructed to be executed during `SaveChanges`.

Comment: During SaveChanges I associate any TrackableBase-Entity to the current User for Created, Modified or Deleted.

Comment: Make sure that you are not setting currently created user into any of your trackable fields.