# Entity Framework 6 - Creating record with Autonumber ID throws DbUpdateException

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm using EF6 in my ASP.Net MVC application. For a particular table my view, update and delete code works but my insert throws a `DbUpdateException`.

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233087
>   Message=Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.
>   Source=EntityFramework
>   StackTrace:
>              at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>              at SupportDiary.Models.SchedulerRequestService.Insert(WRequestViewModel request) in C:\Projects\SupportDiary\SupportDiary\Models\SchedulerRequestService.vb:line 92
>              at SupportDiary.Hubs.WRequestHub.Create(WRequestViewModel request) in C:\Projects\SupportDiary\SupportDiary\Hubs\WRequestHub.vb:line 37
>              at lambda_method(Closure , IHub , Object[] )
>              at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.Incoming(IHubIncomingInvokerContext context)
>         InnerException: 
>              HResult=-2146233087
>              Message=Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.
>              Source=EntityFramework
>              StackTrace:
>                   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.DependencyOrderingError(IEnumerable`1 remainder)
>                   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ProduceCommands()
>                   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
>                   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>                   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
>                   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>                   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
>                   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>              InnerException:

This is the code for Insert and Update... as I said Update works.

```
        Public Overridable Function Insert(request As WRequestViewModel) As WRequestViewModel

        Dim entity As New tWorkRequest()

        entity.Start = request.Start
        entity.[End] = request.[End]
        entity.Title = request.Title
        entity.Diary = request.Diary
        entity.Team = request.Team
        entity.WorkManagerID = request.WorkManagerID
        entity.AssigneeID = request.AssigneeID
        entity.ChangeRef = request.ChangeRef
        entity.Description = request.Description
        entity.ImpactedServers = request.ImpactedServers
        entity.ImpactedServices = request.ImpactedServices
        entity.IsBAU = request.IsBAU
        entity.ProjectRef = request.ProjectRef
        entity.Notes = request.Notes
        entity.IsOOH = request.IsOOH
        entity.IsAllDay = request.IsAllDay
        entity.RecurrenceRule = request.RecurrenceRule
        entity.RecurrenceID = request.RecurrenceID
        entity.RecurrenceException = request.RecurrenceException
        entity.StartTimezone = request.StartTimezone
        entity.EndTimezone = request.EndTimezone
        entity.RequestStatus = request.RequestStatus

        Using de As New SupportDiaryEntities

            de.tWorkRequests.Add(entity)
            de.SaveChanges()

            request.WRequestID = entity.WRequestID

            Return request

        End Using

    End Function

    Public Overridable Sub Update(request As WRequestViewModel)

        Using de As New SupportDiaryEntities

            Dim entity = de.tWorkRequests.FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.WRequestID = request.WRequestID)

            entity.Start = request.Start
            entity.[End] = request.[End]
            entity.Title = request.Title
            entity.Diary = request.Diary
            entity.Team = request.Team
            entity.WorkManagerID = request.WorkManagerID
            entity.AssigneeID = request.AssigneeID
            entity.ChangeRef = request.ChangeRef
            entity.Description = request.Description
            entity.ImpactedServers = request.ImpactedServers
            entity.ImpactedServices = request.ImpactedServices
            entity.IsBAU = request.IsBAU
            entity.ProjectRef = request.ProjectRef
            entity.Notes = request.Notes
            entity.IsOOH = request.IsOOH
            entity.IsAllDay = request.IsAllDay
            entity.RecurrenceRule = request.RecurrenceRule
            entity.RecurrenceID = request.RecurrenceID
            entity.RecurrenceException = request.RecurrenceException
            entity.StartTimezone = request.StartTimezone
            entity.EndTimezone = request.EndTimezone
            entity.RequestStatus = request.RequestStatus

            de.SaveChanges()

        End Using

    End Sub
```

If I drill into entity in the Insert code it as the Autonumber ID field (WRequestId) set to 0

I'm not sure how to fix this issue... searches on-line give details about a bug regarding DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity but this looks like it was a bug in EF4. But I did check my edmx file and this parameter is set correctly on all my ID fields for each table.

This is the EF autogenerated file for the table in question...

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' <auto-generated>
    '     This code was generated from a template.
    '
    '     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
    '     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
    ' </auto-generated>
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Imports System
    Imports System.Collections.Generic

    Partial Public Class tWorkRequest
        Public Property WRequestID As Integer
        Public Property Title As String
        Public Property Start As Date
        Public Property [End] As Date
        Public Property Diary As String
        Public Property Team As String
        Public Property WorkManagerID As Integer
        Public Property AssigneeID As Integer
        Public Property ChangeRef As String
        Public Property Description As String
        Public Property ImpactedServers As String
        Public Property ImpactedServices As String
        Public Property IsBAU As Boolean
        Public Property ProjectRef As String
        Public Property Notes As String
        Public Property IsOOH As Boolean
        Public Property IsAllDay As Boolean
        Public Property RecurrenceRule As String
        Public Property RecurrenceID As Nullable(Of Integer)
        Public Property RecurrenceException As String
        Public Property StartTimezone As String
        Public Property EndTimezone As String
        Public Property RequestStatus As Integer

        Public Overridable Property tWorkRequests1 As ICollection(Of tWorkRequest) = New HashSet(Of tWorkRequest)
        Public Overridable Property tWorkRequest1 As tWorkRequest

    End Class
```

Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: Look at this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153208/unable-to-determine-a-valid-ordering-for-dependent-operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link that @ssanga pointed to had no accepted solution but the general answer seamed to be set the ID to -1. I tried this but got a different exception which pointed to another issue. The EF autogenerated class for the table had the following lines...

```
Public Overridable Property tWorkRequests1 As ICollection(Of tWorkRequest) = New HashSet(Of tWorkRequest)
Public Overridable Property tWorkRequest1 As tWorkRequest
```

Deleting these lines and my Create worked. I then went back to my edmx file in Visual Studio and Generated Model for Database again and these lines did not reappear.

Not sure why they were there in the first place.